# iOS selector does not work for my situation, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector

In my situation, `class C` is **sub class** of `UIViewController`, `class A and B` are **sub classes** of `UIView`, `class A` has a `UIButton`. I write some code like below.

in `class C:`

```
B *b = [[B alloc] init];
[self.view addSubView:b];

A *a = [[A alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@Selector(methodX:)];
[b methodY:a];
```

in `class B`:

```
- (void)methodY:(A *)a
{
   [sef addSubView:a];
}
```

in `class A`:

```
- (id)initWithTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
   [btn addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [self addSubView:btn];
   return self;
}
```

The `methodX:` in `class C` didn't execute.

Is there any wrong with my code?
How does selector work in objective-c?
 Thanks!

Comment: Please review the code, you may have some typos. Do you mean `A *a = [[A alloc] initWithTarget ...`.

Comment: try importing @class UIViewController above line "@interface A" in header file.

Comment: I truly appreciate your attempt to make a simplified version of your code as your problem statement, but in this case I think we need to see the _actual_ code, because this is indeed correct except for one thing -- `UIButton`'s designated initializer is `initWithFrame:` and I don't believe it will function if you use plain `init`.

Comment: Thank you all above! At beginning, I init A & B (subclasses of UIView) in C, then add B to C.view, and then call B's methodY in which method I add A as B's subView, as a result, button in A don't call its selector methodX in C. Now, I init A in B, and add A as B's subview in class B, then button in A call its selector successfully (I passed C as a delegate to B, and made it the target of A's button). I quite want to know why I can't put the selector methodX in C in the beginning situation. @Herçules, could you explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is running very well in my computer. So I guess you just add the button out of `A`, which means your button's frame is not in `A`'s frame

Comment: really? I init A & B (subclasses of UIView) in C, then add B to C.view, and then call B's methodY in which method I add A as B's subView, as a result, button in A don't call his selector methodX in C.

Comment: @fisher Yes. I know what have you done, and it works well here, so you can check if the button is out of A. change `[btn addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` into `[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` and write aMethod in A to see if it can work or not

Answer (score 0):

You wrote, A is a subclass of UIView. Then how are you able to instantiate it through a

```
 [[C alloc]init]
```

in the case of C is a UIViewController? Are you sure that - in runtime - the variable ***a** is a **UIView** type?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be so much wrong in this code.
To start with,

How are you allocating Class C object using this code?.

```
A *a = [[C alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@Selector(methodX:)];
```

Second, if C is a subclass of `UIViewController` , how are you adding it to self in this method? Here self presumably is object of `Class B` which is a `UIView`.

```
- (void)methodY:(C *)c
{
   [sef addSubView:c];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in Class C.

```
A *a = [[A alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@Selector(methodX:)];
```

the target is not right.......

Comment: so, who should be the target? I want to call the selector in C.

Comment: have you try to put the code      UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
   [btn addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; [A addSubView:btn];  in C?